# Error when installing bookmark+ package in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, bookmarks

I'm trying to install bookmarks and I get the error. When I tried byte-compiling the files it also failed. Is there a current git for bookmarks+. Error below:

```
Invalid function: bmkp-menu-bar-make-toggle
```

Here is the full trace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-function bmkp-menu-bar-make-toggle)
  bmkp-menu-bar-make-toggle(t t "Highlight Jump using Crosshairs" "Crosshairs highlighting is %s" "Temporarily highlight visited bookmarks using crosshairs")
  byte-code("\306\307\310   B#\210\306  \311\312\n\211\313\314\315%#\210\306    \316\312\211\317\320\321%#\210\306  \322\312\f\211\323\324\325%#\210\306    \326\312
\211\327\330\331%#\210\306  \332\312\211\333\334\335%#\207" [menu-bar-bookmark-map bmkp-options-menu bmkp-crosshairs-flag bmkp-bmenu-state-file bookmark-save-flag bmkp-save-new-location-flag define-key [options] "Toggle Option" [bmkp-crosshairs-flag] bmkp-menu-bar-make-toggle "Highlight Jump using Crosshairs" "Crosshairs highlighting is %s" "Temporarily highlight visited bookmarks using crosshairs" [bmkp-toggle-saving-menu-list-state] "Autosave *Bookmark List* Display State" "Autosaving of `*Bookmark List*' display state is %s" "Autosave `*Bookmark List*' state (aka \"menu list\") when you quit it" [bmkp-toggle-saving-bookmark-file] "Autosave Bookmark File" "Autosaving of bookmarks is %s" "Automatically save a bookmark after setting or changing it" [bmkp-save-new-location-flag] "Autosave after Relocating" "Autosaving relocated bookmarks is %s" "Automatically save a bookmark after automatically relocating it" [bmkp-prompt-for-tags-flag] "Prompt for Tags when Setting" "Prompting for tags when setting a bookmark is %s" "Prompt for tags when setting a bookmark interactively" bmkp-prompt-for-tags-flag] 9)
  require(bookmark+-key)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*<2>> nil "/home/bigtyme/Dropbox/SyncedPrograms/emacs/loadPath/bookmarkplus/bookmark+.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 5907
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/bigtyme/Dropbox/SyncedPrograms/emacs/loadPath/bookmarkplus/bookmark+.el" "/home/bigtyme/Dropbox/SyncedPrograms/emacs/loadPath/bookmarkplus/bookmark+.el" nil t)
  require(bookmark+)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/bigtyme/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1158
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/bigtyme/.emacs" "/home/bigtyme/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" t t)
  #[nil "\205\264
```

Sorted it out by just downloading the current git version. The version I downloaded from the wiki must have had a bug. Now I have no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, do what chrm recommends: get the latest source files.

Second, `bmkp-menu-bar-make-toggle` is a Lisp macro, defined in `bookmark+-mac.el`.

As always, before byte-compiling any of the source files, be sure you load the source file the defines the macros that those files use.  In this case, load `bookmark+-mac.el` (not `*.elc`) before byte-compiling any of the [***Bookmark+***](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) files.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it, and it works for me.

I downloaded bookmark+ from [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#toc1). All eight files.

Just make sure all files are in a directory from your load-path.

The function (your Emacs can't find) "bmkp-menu-bar-make-toggle", is defined in "bookmark+-mac.el".

Comment: got it sorted by dl'ing the current git. Thanks for the help.